# Prepared SQL statement not 'preparing'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a basic hit counter that I can use on all of my websites.

I have a prepared statement querying both my Go Daddy MySQL server as well as my MAMP MySQL server, and the the statement won't 'Prepare'. Here it is:

```
function hit_counter($url){
        if($mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '',    'DB')){
        $crack = "SELECT hc-id, hc-url, hc-unique_hits, hc-total_hits, hc-last_viewed FROM hit_counter WHERE hc-url =?";
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(crack)){
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $url);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $url, $unique_hits, $total_hits, $last_viewed);
            $stmt->fetch();
            echo "the statement was prepared successfully";
        $total_hits = $total_hits+1;
        $last_viewed = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
        echo $unique_hits;
        if($unique === true){
            $unique_hits = $unique_hits+1;
        }

        $update = 'UPDATE hit_counter set hc-unique_hits=? hc-total_hits=? hc-last_viewed=? WHERE hc-url=?';
            if($stmt= $mysqli->prepare($update)){
            $stmt->bind_param('iiss', $unique_hits, $total_hits, $last_viewed, $url);
            $stmt->execute();
            }else{echo "the update statement wasn't prepared.";}
    }else{echo "The statement wasn't prepared.";}
  }else{echo "the SQL connection wasn't made";}
}
```

I know that it is connecting to the database, but whenever I run the script, it echos the else statement for `if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(crack)){ "The Statement wasn't prepared"`.

Comment: You need comma between SET statements,`set hc-unique_hits=?, hc-total_hits=?,... `

Comment: There is a specific known problem so this isn't really a code review. However in the future if you do want code reviews, there is a [separate Stack Exchange site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Enable error reporting... (both for PDO as for PHP)

Comment: Your "Go Daddy SQL Server" - do you mean Microsoft SQL Server, or MySQL?

Comment: (I've removed the request for a code review - I think the question itself is on-topic, as it relates to a specific problem. Best not to request code review here, as it sounds too general, and could get an otherwise good question closed).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that halfer... So how exactly would I get around this issue?

Comment: OK. "SQL Server" is a Microsoft product. It's best to be accurate with terminology, or your readers may give you the wrong answers.

Comment: What Mihai said, plus your columns contain hyphens. Wrap those in ticks `\``

Comment: are hyphens not allowed in SQL? i just added the ticks, still not preparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your columns contain hyphens which MySQL is interpreting it as `hc` **MINUS** `unique_hits` etc. thinking you want to do a mathematical problem.

You also have missing commas in your SETs

```
UPDATE hit_counter set `hc-unique_hits`=?, `hc-total_hits`=?, `hc-last_viewed`=? WHERE `hc-url`=?
```

It's best to stay away from using hyphens for column names. Use underscores instead.

Using

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
```

would have spotted that error.

Same thing for

```
$crack = "SELECT hc-id, hc-url, hc-unique_hits, hc-total_hits, hc-last_viewed FROM hit_counter WHERE hc-url =?";
```

use backticks around those containing hyphens.

```
$crack = "SELECT `hc-id`, `hc-url`, `hc-unique_hits`, `hc-total_hits`, `hc-last_viewed` 
FROM hit_counter WHERE `hc-url` =?";
```

For more information on Identifier Qualifiers, consult:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html**

Also

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(crack)){
```

should be

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($crack)){
```

where you missed the `$` for `crack`. Otherwise it's treated as a constant.

---

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Another developing tool that is at your disposal is [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Use `var_dump($variable_to_check);` to see what is passing through or not.

Comment: Thank you so much Fred! If I had more rep i'd vote up your answer! It works!

Answer (score 1):

see the value `if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(crack)){` should be

`$crack` , spot the **$** !!

Comment: Yeah.. That was from copy and pasting. In my original code the $ was there. Thanks though!